# How to query for getting count of a column with different values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have written a query in which i am getting result like this.

```
nid  | target_id
2570 | 748
2570 | 756
2570 | 756
2570 | 756
2571 | 799
2572 | 785
```

I have tried count and group by but my result is like

```
nid  | target_id
2570 | 4
2571 | 1
2572 | 1
```

Now I want to write some query to get result something like this

```
nid  | target_id | count(target_id)
2570 | 748       | 1
2570 | 756       | 3
2571 | 799       | 1
2572 | 785       | 1
```

And then get all the nid whose count is greater than 1.
I have tried many queries but not find a luck to find the solution.
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Think `group by` with `having` to filter out the cases where count is greater than 1. Also, do a group by of `nid`  and `target_id`

Answer (score 1):

use `count()` and both column in group by

```
select nid,target_id,count(*) as count_target_id from t
group by nid,target_id
having count_target_id>1
```

Comment: Thanks this was the query which i wanted. You saved my day